# Getting current time using boost

Tags: c++, boost, posix

I figured out how to get the year, month, and date using boost::posix_time().  However I cannot figure out how to get the current hours or minutes.

```
      pt::ptime now = pt::second_clock::local_time();
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << static_cast<int>(now.date().month()) << "/" << now.date().day()
      << "/" << now.date().year();
```

There doesn't appear to be any now.hours options.  Is there another library I should use

Comment: Look at `Boost.DateTime` or `Boost.Chrono` (or `std::chrono`). They're preferable over `posix_time`

Comment: I looked there, the problem I am having is that all the examples are about date insertion.  I am trying to get the date from the computers internal clock.

Comment: This is the example it gives for converting date to string       std::string s("2001-10-9"); //2001-October-09
      date d(from_simple_string(s));
      std::cout << to_simple_string(d) << std::endl;

Comment: I cannot find any documentation of what to put in date d() to get the current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `std::chrono`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   system_clock::time_point p = system_clock::now();
   auto t = system_clock::to_time_t(p);

   std::cout << std::ctime(&t) << std::endl; // e.g Tue Dec 27 17:21:29 2011

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a much better solution that the one I was working on.  I was in one of those can't see the forest full of trees dev holes.

Comment: As a footnote, there are some proposals to add `date` and `datetime` to the library aswell, as of now we have to resort to using C style functionality for that part, one of those proposals is [n1900](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1900.pdf)